# Subset data frame where values are greater than another data frame

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame with 3 columns of data (a,b,c) and 1 column of categories with multiple instances of each category (class).

```
set.seed(273)
a <- floor(runif(20,0,100))
b <- floor(runif(20,0,100))
c <- floor(runif(20,0,100))
class <- floor(runif(20,0,6))

df1 <- data.frame(a,b,c,class)

print(df1)
    a  b  c class
1  31 73 28     3
2  44 33 57     3
3  19 35 53     0
4  68 70 39     4
5  92  7 57     2
6  13 67 23     3
7  73 50 14     2
8  59 14 91     5
9  37  3 72     5
10 27  3 13     4
11 63 28  0     5
12 51  7 35     4
13 11 36 76     3
14 72 25  8     5
15 23 24  6     3
16 15  1 16     5
17 55 24  5     5
18  2 54 39     1
19 54 95 20     3
20 60 39 65     1
```

And I have another data frame with the same 3 columns of data and category column, however this only has one instance per category (class).

```
a <- floor(runif(6,0,20))
b <- floor(runif(6,0,20))
c <- floor(runif(6,0,20))
class <- seq(0,5)

df2 <- data.frame(a,b,c,class)

print(df2)
   a  b  c class
1  8 15 13     0
2  0  3  6     1
3 14  4  0     2
4  7 10  6     3
5 18 18 16     4
6 17 17 11     5
```

How to I subset the first data frame so that only rows where a, b, and c are all greater than the value in the second data frame for each class?  For example, I only want rows where `class == 0` if `a > 8 & b > 15 & c > 13`.

Note that I don't want to join the data frames, as the second data frame is the lowest acceptable value for the the first data frame.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have added a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

As commented by Frank this can be done with *non-equi* joins.

```
    # coerce to data.table
tmp <- setDT(df1)[
  # non-equi join to find which rows of df1 fulfill conditions in df2
  setDT(df2), on = .(class, a > a, b > b, c > c), rn, nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE]

# return subset in original order of df1
df1[sort(tmp)]
```

> ```
>      a  b  c class
>  1: 31 73 28     3
>  2: 44 33 57     3
>  3: 19 35 53     0
>  4: 68 70 39     4
>  5: 92  7 57     2
>  6: 13 67 23     3
>  7: 73 50 14     2
>  8: 11 36 76     3
>  9:  2 54 39     1
> 10: 54 95 20     3
> 11: 60 39 65     1
> ```

The parameter `which = TRUE` returns a vector of the matching row numbers instead of the joined data set. This saves us from creating a row id column before the join. (Credit to @Frank for reminding me of the `which` parameter!)

Note that there is no row in `df1` which fulfills the condition for `class == 5` in `df2`. Therefore, the parameter `nomatch = 0L` is used to exclude non-matching rows from the result.

This can be put together in a "one-liner":

```
setDT(df1)[sort(df1[setDT(df2), on = .(class, a > a, b > b, c > c), nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE])]
```